# Swing start simulation from Swing interface and write from thread. How?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

The problem is that I lost myself in my code.
First of all, my project is supposed to simulate a shop queue.
Now, I made my Swing Interface where I get my data. When Simulate button is pressed, I want to start the simulation. The trick is that I'm not sure how to write in the fields without creating a new Interface.

My Interface code (I left only what I thought it was important):

```
   public class Interfata extends JFrame {

   public void UpdateTextField(String name, int i)
   {
      switch(i){
      case 0: this.txtField8.setText(name); break; 
      case 1: this.txtField9.setText(name); break;
      case 2: this.txtField10.setText(name); break;
      case 3: this.txtField11.setText(name); break;
      case 4: this.txtField12.setText(name); break;
      case 5: this.txtField7.setText(name); break;
      default : this.txtField7.setText(name); break;
    }
   }
   private Interfata() {

    mybutton = new JButton("Simulate");
    mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Magazin shop = new Magazin(toNumber(txtField6.getText()),
                    toNumber(txtField1.getText()), toNumber(txtField2
                            .getText()), toNumber(txtField3.getText()),
                    toNumber(txtField4.getText()), toNumber(txtField5
                            .getText()));

            shop.simulation();
            }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Interfata interfataMea = new Interfata();
    interfataMea.setTitle("Shop Simulator");
    interfataMea.setSize(1000, 700);
    interfataMea.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    interfataMea.setVisible(true);
   }
 }
```

I create the thread in class `Magazin` where I have the `simulation()` methode:

```
 public void simulation() {

        for (int i = 0; i < nrClienti; i++) {
            int aux = shortestQueue(cozi);
            Client c = generateClient();
            new Threads(cozi[aux], c, aux, avgWaitTime).start();

         }
        }
```

Threads extends Thread and here is the code:

```
  public class Threads extends Thread {

   private Coada coada;
   private Client c;
   private int i, avgWaitTime;

   public Threads(Coada q, Client c, int aux, int avgWaitTime) {
      this.coada = q;
      this.c = c;
      this.i = aux;
      this.avgWaitTime = avgWaitTime;
    }

   @Override
   public void run() {

       coada.enque(c);

       int s = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < coada.getSize(); i++){
           s = s + coada.getClient().getservTime();
       }
       avgWaitTime=avgWaitTime+s;
       try {
           sleep(s);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // waiting to finish service time
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        intf.UpdateTextField(coada.toString(), i); } });


      coada.deque();


       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
       intf.UpdateTextField(coada.toString(), i); } });


        }
     }
```

It just has to insert an object in the Queue, show the Queue in the JTextField, remove an object and reshow. I found the invokeLater example, but it would require making a new Interface intf. Or not, I'm lost. 
Please help. Thank you very much for your time!

P.S. If I made something unclear or I forgot to mention something, please do tell.

Comment: *"The problem is that I lost myself in my code."*  A great way to 'find yourself' is to hone the code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As an aside, either you forgot to ask a question, or forgot to add a '?' to it.

Comment: `"The trick is that I'm not sure how to write in the fields without creating a new Interface."` -- This is very unclear to me. Could you expand on this issue since it appears to be your main problem?

Comment: Well, the deal was that I wanted to write in those `JtextFields` from my `Thread`, without having to instanciate a new `Interfata`. I solved my problem by making them static. Everything works fine now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The trick is that I'm not sure how to write in the fields without creating a new Interface.

The problem is you're passing the contents of the textfields to the `Magazin` when you create it to start the simulation. Afterwards (i.e., as it runs) the `Magazin` has no way to update the textfields. Instead, try passing a reference to the `Interfata` that the `Magazin` stores in a `final` field variable. Then it will be possible to use this variable inside an `invokeLater` to update the textfields. It will also be possible to get the text in the fields using `invokeAndWait`. In general, `invokeAndWait` can be used in place of `invokeLater` when there's no downside to blocking the calling thread for a short while.